# missing SQL conditions for table definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I would like to know what condition to add to my table definition to not allow to create a new row when these fields doctorId, dateApt, hourApt are for the same date and hour and doctorId.

```
ex:  aptId  ClientId  doctorId  dateApt     TimeApt  IsAvaiable
     1      Null      1         2014/01/29  09:00    True
     2      Null      1         2014/01/29  09:00    True    <== not allowing this
     3      Null      1         2014/01/29  10:00    True    <== ok bc not same hour and date
     4      Null      2         2014/01/29  09:00    True    <== ok not same doctorId
```

here is the table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Appointement] (
    [aptId]       INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [clientId]    INT      NULL,
    [doctorId]    INT      NOT NULL,
    [dateApt]     DATE     NOT NULL,
    [hourApt]     TIME (7) NOT NULL,
    [IsAvailable] BIT      NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([rdvId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_doctorID] FOREIGN KEY ([doctorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Doctor] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_clientID] FOREIGN KEY ([clientId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id_user])
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL? You can do the check there. This seems like a business rule rather than an architectural requirement.

Comment: @rhughes  I was thinking we can add a rules in the table definition to avoid this

Comment: I think you can use INSTEAD OF triggers to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a unique constraint on those columns:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Appointement
  ADD CONSTRAINT uAppt UNIQUE (doctorId, dateApt, hourAp)
```

Or add it when you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Appointement] (
     [aptId]       INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [clientId]    INT      NULL,
     [doctorId]   INT      NOT NULL,
     [dateApt]   DATE     NOT NULL,
     [hourApt]  TIME (7) NOT NULL,
     [IsAvailable] BIT      NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([rdvId] ASC),
     CONSTRAINT [fk_doctorID] FOREIGN KEY ([doctorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Doctor] ([Id]),
     CONSTRAINT [fk_clientID] FOREIGN KEY ([clientId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id_user]),
     CONSTRAINT uAppt UNIQUE (doctorId, dateApt, hourAp)
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this line 
     CONSTRAINT uniqueAPT UNIQUE (doctorId, dateApt, hourApt)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a `unique constraint`.

```
CONSTRAINT [UQ_DoctorID_DateApt_HourApt] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    [DoctorId], [DateApt], [HoursApt]
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

(This is syntax for part of `CREATE TABLE` statement)

Comment: He needs it to be unique to the same hour so I don't think a unique constraing will work

Comment: @AbeMiessler: The way I read it, the hour column must be unique, not the hour exactly ... Meaning 9:30 is different from 9:00.. These are appointment times, which makes sense. Each appointment for each doctor must be unique on a given date and time. The unique constraint accomplishes this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an INSTEAD OF trigger that ignores duplicate appointments:

create trigger ignoreDups on Appointement 
instead of insert
as
  declare @cId int
  set @cid = (select clientId from inserted)
  declare @did int
  set @did = (select doctorId from inserted)
  declare @dApt date
  set @dApt = (select dateApt from inserted)
  declare @hApt time
  set @hApt = (select hourApt from inserted)
  declare @avail bit
  set @avail = (select IsAvailable from inserted)

if (select count(*) from Appointement
      where @dApt = dateApt and  @hApt = hourApt and  doctorid=@did) = 0
          insert Appointement (clientId, doctorid, dateApt, hourApt, IsAvailable) values (@cid, @did, @dApt,@hApt,@avail)

Here's the [sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ace9b/7)

Comment: why doing this if CONSTRAINT uniqueAPT UNIQUE (doctorId, dateApt, hourApt) is doing the work and it is a lot simpler?

Comment: It creates an index that may be unnecessary and an error message will be issued that will need to be handled using a constraint.